# sap.ui.table.Table addRow() example

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Can anyone give me a short example of how to add a simple row to a sap.ui.table.Table using JavaScript in Neptune? Let's say I have a table with three columns. My approach was the following:

`MyTable.addRow({"COLUMN1":"Text1", "COLUMN2":"Text2", "COLUMN3":"Text3"});`

Unfortunately the code doesn't seem to work as my table is staying empty. Also there is no simple example to find on any website.
Thank's for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer. For anyone else, who needs it:

```
let data;
let model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

data = [{
    Column1: "Text1",
    Column2: "Text2",
    Column3: "Text3",
        },
    ];
        
model.setData({modelData: data});
MyTable.setModel(model).bindRows("/modelData");
```

Answer (score 0):

[addRow](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table%23methods/addRow) expects a [sap.ui.table.Row](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Row) as argument.

```
MyTable.addRow(
    new sap.ui.table.Row(sID, oParams)
        .addCell(new sap.m.text("foo")
        .addCell(new sap.m.text("bar")
);
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. But what do I add for sID and oParams in this case?

Comment: If you don't need an id or params you can leave them empty. The params you can look up in the linked documentation.